# How to make the View update instant in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, date, if-statement, swiftui

I have a `Text` that acts as a timer with different values of my array. And it displays with `timerIntervalSinceNow`.

The problem is when it reaches zero it should show zero to but that does not happen before clicking again on the screen. If I do not click on it it keeps going up since it is `timeIntervalSinceNow`, but when I click it switches to the `Text` with `0 sec`.

Any way on telling SwiftUI to do this by itself without clicking?

```
if(exerciseTime[value].timeIntervalSinceNow > 0) {
    Text(exerciseTime[value], style:.relative).foregroundColor(.white).font(.largeTitle).padding(.top, 30)                                   
} else {
    Text("0 sec").foregroundColor(.white).font(.largeTitle).padding(.top, 30)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `exerciseTime[value]` never changes, so the view is not redrawn.

Even though `exerciseTime[value].timeIntervalSinceNow` might be different, the actual `exerciseTime[value]` remains constant.

I recommend you use a `Timer` with an `ObservableObject` instead:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var timer: AnyCancellable?

    @Published var currentDate = Date()

    func start(endDate: Date) {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.currentDate = $0
                if self.currentDate >= endDate {
                    self.timer = nil
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and use it in your view:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var exerciseTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 15, to: Date())!
    @StateObject private var timer = TimerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if timer.currentDate < exerciseTime {
                Text(exerciseTime, style: .relative)
            } else {
                Text("0 sec")
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .onAppear {
            timer.start(endDate: exerciseTime)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is AnyCancellable ?

Comment: @LucasGoldner It's from Combine framework, I updated my answer with import statements.

Comment: Ah thanks a bunch best answer to this problem I have found yet!!