# Declare Timer.TimerPublisher

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'd like to use `@AppStorage("interval")` to initialize `timer`. I cannot do this in the struct initialization because I'll get an error. But if I try to do declare `timer` first and initialize it in `startTimer()`, I get all sorts of errors as well. What's the best way to make sure `interval` is available to initialize `timer`? Here's the relevant code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("interval") var interval = 5.0
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    //or try this:
    @State private var timer: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>?
    //or try this:
    @State private var timer: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>? = nil

    init() {
        startTimer()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't hold it in view, move it instead in view model class to manage by reference properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep `Timer` inside the `View`, you can declare it as `AnyCancellable` and then use `assign` or `sink` to assign the value.

Here is a possible example:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("interval") var interval = 5.0
    @State private var timer: AnyCancellable?
    
    @State private var currentDate = Date()
    let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 30, to: Date())!
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(currentDate, style: .relative)
            .onAppear(perform: startTimer)
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .assign(to: \.currentDate, on: self)
            // .sink { self.currentDate = $0 } // alternatively, if you need more then just assigning the value
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.cancel()
    }
}
```

However, it might be better to keep the timer logic out of the `View` like in this example:

- [How to make the View update instant in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556248/8697793)

Comment: @Daan *All I want, really, is to initialize Timer.TimerPublisher with the @AppStorage("interval")* - this is simple, you can't do it. `@AppStorage` is not available in `init`. In `init` you can only read data from `UserDefaults` in a *standard* way (`UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "interval")`). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43550813/8697793